# Concatenate - sign with numeric in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to Concatenate - sign with numeric I tried but not working. I just want to add - sign with the calculation result value. Code is mentioned below.

```
if ({Sp_ProductLedger;1.QtyOut}) >0 then
"-" &({#RTotal0} + {Sp_ProductLedger;1.Opbal});
```

Comment: What is the output? Or do you get an error message in the edtior? Would it be enough to multiply the result by -1? Or maybe use the format of the field to append a "1"?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the way you are trying to concatenate your fields for output.  I did a test with your formula replacing your field names with similar fields in one of my reports and it output the result as expected with the negative sign in front.  Please provide some examples of the output or errors you are getting so we can help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a numeric result that is negative, multiply by -1 instead of adding a minus sign (which would result in a string rather than a number).